# Where does the new line come from. Read from a file and put in a string. Then output to the console

Tags: c#, string, text-files, newline

I want to understand why there is a newline when console.writeline outputs this text which is from a string variable. "Now is the time for all good people".

```
    String filename = @"C:\data\chars.txt";

        TextWriter aText = File.AppendText(filename);
        String lineToWrite = "Now is the time for all good people";
        aText.WriteLine(lineToWrite);
        aText.Close();
        StreamReader aStream = new StreamReader(filename);
        string words = "";
        char letter;
        while (aStream.Peek() != -1)
        {
            letter = Convert.ToChar(aStream.Read());
            Console.WriteLine(letter);
            words += letter;
        }
        aStream.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(words);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Console writeline is only called once, but the terminal screen show the string line by line, when there are 3 lines in the file, so if I run it again there will be 4 lines on the screen, each on there own line, where does the newline character come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aText.WriteLine(lineToWrite);
```

You are appending to the file using WriteLine method. This appends a newline character at the end of each line. When you are printing it to the console this newline character gets printed.
The word at the end of each line contains the newline character and it gets printed.

Comment: Does the read method read the newline character and is it concatenated to words?

Comment: yes offcourse.. Read method reads one character at a time including the control or non-printable characters